# insert into table - replace column names and values by arrays

Tags: php, mysql

two arrays:

```
$columns = array('mail', 'phone', 'author', 'title');
$values = array('some mail', 'some phone', 'an author', 'a title');
```

Is it possible something like this:

```
$sql = "insert into actual (" . implode(', ', $columns) . ") values (" . implode(', ', $values) . ")";
$st = $db->prepare($sql);
$st->execute();  // line 23
```

I tried and got a syntax error on line `23`.

Comment: try show us the var_dump($sql)

Comment: the implode  don't wrap the string with proper quotes ..

Comment: Your values should be in quotes, better still is to use place holders for each value and bind the `$values` array in the `execute()`

Comment: @scaisEdge, you probably mean `var_dump($columns)`?

Comment: no .. i mean var__dump($sql)  .. the result for your query string building  .. anyway the error is clear you have not quote around string using implode

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write this as a prepared statement with place holders, you need to repeat `?` for each field and then pass the values using `bindParam()` (assuming mysqli)...

```
$columns = array('mail', 'phone', 'author', 'title');
$values = array('some mail', 'some phone', 'an author', 'a title');
// Create place holders (need to remove last comma - done in build of SQL)
$valuesPlace = str_repeat("?,", count($values));
$sql = "insert into actual (" . implode(', ', $columns) . ") 
    values (" . rtrim($valuesPlace, ",") . ")";

$st = $db->prepare($sql);
// Bind a list of string values (big assumption)
$st->bindParam(str_repeat("s", count($values)), ...$values);
$st->execute();  // line 23
```

Comment: While this is a solution, this ends up being a really crappy imitation of a proper ORM. If you need this sort of dynamic query building, which can really simplify code design, use an actual ORM.